# Setting up coverity for the Cygwin build environment

Tags: code-coverage, coverity

I build my project using the cygwin shell inside Windows 10 OS. My project does not build natively in the windows shell.

How can I configure the coverity to run in cygwin shell instead of the default windows shell ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "cd ~/path/to/desired; my_build_command" in the coverity build.